# Bash script to remove all lines in a text file untill a string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, filter

I have a file with lots of words like:

```
one
two
three
four
tree
house
cat
dog
etc
```

and I want to remove all words until "house" in such a way to get only:

```
cat
dog
etc
```

Answer (score 6):

```
sed -n '0,/^house$/d;p' input.txt
```

Comment: This one prints out the whole file for me. (Running sed on OS X 10.6.6)

Comment: GNU `sed` supports 0 as an address, but others do not. The difference between `0,/regex/` and `1,/regex/` is that if the regex matches the first line, the 0 form will end the range, but the 1 form will wait until the next match of the regex to end the range.

Comment: How is this different to: `sed '0,/^house$/d' input.txt` ? That is, why the `-n` and `;p` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    BEGIN                  { noprint = 1; cue = ARGV[1]; ARGV[1] = ""}
    (!noprint)             { print }
    (noprint && $0 == cue) { noprint = 0 }
' house textfile
```

Comment: Hey, what's with the -1? This works with `gawk` 3.1.5 on Debian 5.0.

Comment: Works OK if I remove the < between the cue and the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with a Perl one-liner, which you can of course incorporate into a bash script.

```
$ perl -ne 'print if $ok; $ok=1 if /^house$/' sample.txt 
cat
dog
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the Unix text editor ed for this kind of task. Note that ed reads the entire file into memory and edits files in-place without previous backup though.

```
# prints result to stdout
printf '%s\n' H ',g/^house$/1,/^house$/d' ',p' | ed -s file
printf '%s\n' H ',g/^house$/1,//d' ',p' | ed -s file  # short version

# edits file in-place
printf '%s\n' H ',g/^house$/1,/^house$/d' wq | ed -s file
```

For more information on ed please see:

"Editing files with the ed text editor from scripts",

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed